# Combining a non-*-projection and "returning" in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have two working statements to insert a row into a table named `document` with Slick.

The first one inserts all columns, taken from the `row` object and returns the ID generated by Postgres:

```
(Tables.Document returning Tables.Document.map(_.id)) +=
    DocumentRow(id=-1, name="Name", fulltext="The text")
```

The second one ignores the column named `fulltext` and only inserts the `name` but does not return the generated ID:

```
Tables.Document.map(r => (r.name)) += ("Name")
```

How can I combine both (limiting the insert to a subset of columns *and* returning the generated ID at the same time)?

*Background:*

The reason why I want to exclude the fulltext column from the insert is the fact that it is of Postgres type `tsvector`, but the generated Slick code treats it as a String. At insert time the value (even if `null` or `None`) is converted into some text type which is incompatible with `tsvector` and raises an exception. I found no solution to insert a `tsvector` without an additional library. Please comment if you think there is and I should be rather following this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I believe the right way is to fix `tsvector` issue, I don't have enough experience with Postres to help you with it. As for your workaround, you can do it and the code should look something like this:

```
(Tables.Document.map(r => (r.name)) returning Tables.Document.map(_.id)) += ("Name")
```

If you split it into parts you can see that first you create a `Query` as in your second example but then rather than apply `+=` to it immediately you first chain it with `returning` and only then call `+=`.

P.S. What is the issue with using some additional Postres-aware library?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this anymore, but this did not compile yesterday! :-) Must have messed up with parenthesis or whatever. Anyways, it works now. Thanks!